# A good old-fashioned book burning: the literature tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

So, we have a [literature](/questions/tagged/literature) tag. I don't think we need this. Most of the questions that have it are... not good (a good 33% are closed). And those that are OK probably don't need it.

Shall we burn it? Especially since, even after it gets removed, it may well come back.

Comment: 15 posts...edit them I'd say. I'm not sure it's very likely that it will come back.

Comment: Whatever old-fashioned book-burnings were, "good" is one of the last things I'd associate with them.

Comment: Just voted to close/delete all those that aren't currently. Meta will get rid of it shortly...

Comment: Now let's do the [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/books) tag!  ;)

Comment: [805 questions that could be closed as Not-Constructive](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[books]+closed%3A0)?

Comment: @Aditya By all means propose that for the top voted one while I hide under this desk.

Comment: @Aditya Please don't vote to close the top question on that list. The C++ community actively maintains it, so it's an exceptional case.  Several of the other top questions there are already locked, but I do think the vast majority of those that remain can be closed.

Comment: @Bart - a desk won't protect you from the resulting nuclear blast.

Comment: @Bart, BilltheLizard - I don't yet have 3k rep on SO.. So I am neither flagging them nor Voting to Close them...